# In ruby how to parse json array contained in json into class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the bubble wrap library which is working well to parse this json into classes of Item, the problem I have is how to extract the values of notifications. I've tried parsing the key/value for notifications the same way as the parent but I've been getting errors on the line that parses (Invalid Selector sent to 0x34..) I'm guessing it's no longer valid json once I read the member property only? Thanks!

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "username": "96u39nos9u",
        "password": "estanimiautem",
        "notifications": [
            {
                "notification": {
                    "body": "Eum dolorem aliquam animi ut."
                }
            },
            {
                "notification": {
                    "body": "verities"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the snippet to parse into objects (works except for the notifications)

```
BW::HTTP.get("http://resturl/api/v1/users") do |response|                                                              

  mydata = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)["users"]

  mydata.each {
    |item|
    aItem = Item.new(item)
    @data << aItem
  }

  @table.dataSource = self
  @table.delegate = self
  self.view.addSubview @table
end
```

the class which converts json into properties

```
class Item                                                                                                                                                  
  PROPERTIES = [:id, :name, :status, :email, :notifications]
  PROPERTIES.each { |prop|
    p prop
    attr_accessor prop
  }

  def initialize(hash = {})
    p "initialize"
    p hash
    p "end initialize"
    hash.each { |key, value|
      p key
      p value
      if key.to_s == "notifications"
        // pass the values into a local array or separate class?
      end
      if PROPERTIES.member? key.to_sym
        self.send((key.to_s + "=").to_s, value)
      end
    }
  end                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

Comment: Sorry, this Ruby code is a little hard to understand. What does 'p' do exactly? Also, if your block is more than one line, it's best to use a do-end block rather than using '{}'. So for example it's better to do mydata.each do |item| ... end.

Comment: @freddyrangel p just prints to console - its a ruby motion project btw I didn't mention that

Comment: "p" is similar to "puts" but shows the inspect value of the object instead of the to_s value, so easier for debugging.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p

Comment: Can't require bubblewrap outside a motion project so it's gonna be difficult for us to debug this. Can't you just use the core `JSON` library?

Comment: A little circuitous, but what if you convert the hash back into json? `mydata = BW::JSON.parse(hash["notifications"].as_json)

Comment: plus `p` is, like, three chars shorter to type :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good start would be to remove all the unnecessary complication in your code. Then it will be a lot easier to diagnose what's going on.

```
BW::HTTP.get("http://resturl/api/v1/users") do |response|                                                              

  mydata = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_s)["users"]

  @data = mydata.collect{|i| Item.new(i)}


  @table.dataSource = self
  @table.delegate = self
  self.view.addSubview @table
end
```

And

```
class Item                                                                                                                                                  
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :status, :email, :notifications


  def initialize(hash = {})
    @id = hash['id']
    @name = hash['name']
    @status = hash['status']
    @email = hash['email']
    @notification = hash['notification']
  end                                                                                                                                                       
end
```